# How to animate icons/images on website with code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to learn how sites [like this one](https://stripe.com/us/customers) are able to move their images and create animations with code.

I have basic HTML/CSS knowledge, and from looking at their [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjbnY.jpg),  I see that their pixels change continuously. The image below doesn't show that obviously, but I'd like to know how they are able to make it so that their translate pixels are constantly changing? Does it involve a javascript file somewhere? and if so, where is that located?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

Using CSS, you an create animations using the `@keyframes` keyword.

```
@keyframes myAnimationName {
    from {
        transform:translate(0px,0px);
    }
    to {
        transform:translate(100px,100px);
    }
}

img {
    animation: myAnimationName;
}
```

Method 2: Using JavaScript

(A little bit of CSS)

```
img {
    position:absolute;
    transition:1s;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

JS:

```
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
img.style.left = "100px";
img.style.top = "100px";
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to learn how sites like this one are able to move their images and create animations with code.

In general, animations are mostly powered by CSS. CSS turns out to be much more performant than animations created using JavaScript, and they are also more simple to implement, so using CSS for animations is considered a best-practice.

> I'd like to know how they are able to make it so that their translate pixels are constantly changing?

As the answerer Caleb H. mentioned, you can use keyframes to achieve the effect Stripe is doing using pure CSS. You should [read more about CSS animations here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).

If you look carefully at Stripe's code, you'll notice that the elements using the [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) CSS function to move the elements from off-screen to the right (2800px on the X axis) to off screen to the left (-200px on the X axis).

This can absolutely be achieved using [keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)! Here's a simple example that would move a box slightly off-screen to the left, to somewhere very far to the right. Run the code snippet below to see a working example.

```css
@keyframes stripeScroll1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100px); 
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(2000px); 
  }
}

@keyframes stripeScroll2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px); 
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(2100px); 
  }
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: blue;
  
  animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-name: stripeScroll1;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: pink;
  
  animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-name: stripeScroll2;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.box-1, .box-2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A Simple Animation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box-1"></div>
    <div class="box-2"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Does it involve a javascript file somewhere? and if so, where is that located?

It appears Stripe is using JavaScript to rapidly adjust the CSS positioning (using a JavaScript framework like React or Angular, no doubt), which is why you see the numbers constantly changing, but unfortunately you won't be able to read JavaScript code on most modern websites like Stripe's, since they undergo [minification](https://www.incapsula.com/cdn-guide/glossary/minification.html) while being bundled for production.

Nonetheless, Keyframes are a beginner-friendly way to achieve the same thing.